# Support Screen Issue?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-screen-support

My application supports screens which are **large** and **xlarge**. I make that feature within manifest file.

```
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="528"/>
```

But I need to include a device whose form factor is **Phone** -not Tablet- in Google Play Developer Console. This device's name is **Huawei MediaPad T2 7.0**. How can I include only this device without enabling normalScreens in manifest?

Comment: what about using `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp` property

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put specific device model in your manifest. Google Play documentation tells us that the app's device compatibility list is based on the manifest file settings.

For example, if your APK's manifest file specifies a large screen size, your supported list will include devices with the required screen sizes that can access your app on Google Play. So the console simple reflects what you have in the manifest and you cannot specify device model specifically in the manifest.

So you just need to include normalScreens in support, that's it.

Comment: If I include normalScreens in support, the app will support some of mobile phones, right?

Comment: you see, when you set it to true in manifest then you'll see in the console the list of ALL devises with such screens but you can manually exclude some and leave only the ones you want to support. This functionality you can find in the console ! Not in manifest. First add support for normalScreens and then just include the ones you need via the console manually